# reprepro failing to add file: "Skipping inclusion"

Tags: ubuntu, debian, repository

I have a few dozen air-gapped machines that I want to upload very specific patches onto. My solution is to create a private repository and have each individual machine updates their `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. I have a list of deb packages that I want to be in the repository.

I am using this guide to create a private repository [HOWTO: Create debian repositories with reprepro](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/03/23/create-debian-repository-reprepro/) using repropro.

When I try to import the a deb package, I get an error:

```
$ reprepro -b repo/ includedeb yakkety python3_3.5.1-4_amd64.deb 
Skipping inclusion of 'python3' '3.5.1-4' in 'yakkety|main|amd64', as 
it has already '3.5.1-4'.
```

I am not certain what is causing this error. Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Package with same version already in your distribution. 
Use 
reprepro ls python3
To check it